# Convert to WAV using FFMPEG for pipe into LAME?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an AAC file into WAV in order to pipe the output into LAME. I'm looking to do this, specifically:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.m4a" | sort | while read file; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 - | lame -b 256 -m s -q 0 - output.mp3
done
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:'
Warning: unsupported audio format
```

Is there a way to specify the `-acodec` for the output? Reading the manpage now.

I know that I can convert to MP3 within FFMPEG, but that's not what I want to do ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the prompt from [Miati's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/176911/5614), I figured it out:

```
ffmpeg -i file.m4a -f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 - | \
    lame -m s -b 320 -q 0 --replaygain-accurate - file.mp3
```

The format needs to be set when outputting to stdout.

Comment: This is the minimum you need: `ffmpeg -i "file.any" -f wav - | lame - "file.mp3"`

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error, FFmpeg is greedy on stdin. If you are going to run FFmpeg in a read loop you need to turn it off

```
ffmpeg -nostdin
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/e1a5402/misc/thumbnail.sh#L45)

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run?

```
ffmpeg -i file.m4a -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 file.wav
```

It worked fine for me.

If it errors out, the previous error makes sense, you may not have support to decode aac or encode wav.  Then the pipe fails because it doesn't know what to format it as.
Possible solutions at that point would be to compile ffmpeg with support for the formats (my guess aac as I believe it's non-free)

Try using -f
According to this [page](http://earthwithsun.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay), when output is set as stdout (or -), the container format must be manually set. The post says to use matroska (or .mkv container)

```
ffmpeg -i file.m4a -acodec pcm_s16le -f matroska -ac 2 -
```

Comment: I kind of need to pipe. I'm not interested in wasting the creation of a file if I can help it. Your example works, but I need to pipe.

Comment: The purpose of it wasn't a solution, but rather troubleshooting if your ffmpeg command was correctly formatted. After further looking http://earthwithsun.com/questions/322216/how-can-i-pipe-output-of-ffmpeg-to-ffplay, it appears you have to set a container format with -f if outputting to -